# Using cv.glmnet on a very large data-set

Tags: r, large-data-volumes, glmnet

I use the `cv.glmnet()` function to estimate a penalized multinomial logit model.
Since the datset is far too large to make things reproducable, I show the call of the function:

```
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x= X, 
                  y=as.numeric(dat$choice_t) ,
                  family="multinomial", 
                  type.multinomial = "grouped", 
                  parallel = TRUE,
                  alpha=0,
                  nfolds=5)
```

Using my code on a "small" subset of my entire data-set works fine, but **including all 30 mio. observations** lead to the following error:

```
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  lange Vektoren (Argument 5) nicht unterstÃ¼tzt in  .C
Ruft auf: cv.glmnet -> glmnet -> lognet -> .Fortran
```

Appart form the many oberservations I include many interaction terms - 50 in total.

I allready work on a server using 16 GB for all 8 CPU cores.

**What can I do to avoid this problem?**

**Are there any options I can set?**

Comment: Does `glmnet` on the full dataset work?

Comment: Look into `biglm` and `bigmemory`?

Comment: @Hong Ooi - thanks for the quick reply! I did not check that so far but will do that tomorrow. Using multinom() without the interaction term was possible...

Comment: @ Chi Pak thanks for your reply! Is it possible to perform a penalized multinomial regression with biglm or bigmemory ?